# Run procedure after replication finish

Tags: oracle, triggers, stream, replication

I have 2 dbs and use replication between them to replicate one schema. (Oracle Streams)

Is it possible to add on one table trigger or smthing like this to be invoked after new data added in remote db (better for each row)?

I try triggers on update and insert - they are not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we replicate tables between 2 dbs also we replicate triggers.

But apply process on dest db disable triggers on dest table.

To force trigger execution on dest db need to run such procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY('<trigger_owner>', 'trigger_name', FALSE);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what sort of logic you are trying to implement, you would either want to create a custom apply handler or an apply rule that would include your custom actions.  The chapter in the Streams Concepts and Administration manual on [Advanced Rule Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17069/strms_adrules.htm) is probably a good place to start to see what options are available.

Comment: I want that apply handler fire insert and update trigger when working